# Fineuploader: Process a file before uploading

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader, fileapi

I need to process binary data of every file that is uploaded to Amazon S3 through (with and without chunking). Do you know if there is any function/signal in Fineuploader that I could use to process every binary chunk/file ?:

For example:

```
preupload(data_chunk)
 process(data_chunk);
return data_chunk
```

This would be very useful for my project.

Cheers,
Piotr

Comment: What do you want to do with the files, exactly?

Comment: I have few custom written stream functions that I want to apply to the binary stream.

Comment: And do you want to upload the modified files only, or the modified files and the original files, or...?

Comment: I just want to upload the modified files. Possibly larger than 1GB.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this would be to grab the `File`/`Blob` in a `submit` event handler, return false from your handler (to tell Fine Uploader to ignore the file), process it, then send the processed file back to Fine Upload via the `addBlobs` method.  You'll need to be sure that your submit event handler knows which files to process/ignore and which files to "leave alone".  One way you can do this is to add a property to the processed `Blob` that your submit event handler looks for.

Since Stack Overflow's code editor is awful, I've created [a gist to demonstrate this](https://gist.github.com/rnicholus/3066f37594a6aefcd575).

```
function process(file) {
  var processedVersion = /*do stuff and return a processed version */
  
  processedVersion.processedByMyApp = true;
  uploader.addBlobs(processedVersion);
}

var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
  request: {
    endpoint: "/uploads"
  },
  
  callbacks: {
    onSubmit: function(id) {
      var file = this.getFile(id);
      if (!file.processedByMyApp) {
        process(file);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
});
```